# Backbone collection where clause with OR condition

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have searched for this for quite some time but could not get a way to have a where clause with or condition. For example if I have a collection `Cars` and I try to do the following:

```
Cars.where({
            model: 1998,
            color: 'Black',
            make: 'Honda' 
          })
```

So what the above will do is search for a `car` whose `model` is `1998` AND `color` is `Black` AND `make` is `Honda`.

But I require a way to get `cars` which have either of the three conditions true.

Answer (score 11):

```
Cars.filter(function(car) {
    return car.get("model") === 1998 ||
        car.get("color") === "Black" ||
        car.get("make") === "Honda";
});
```

Comment: Hi @Lukas. Thanks for responding. But this is not what I was looking for. I had this solution in mind. The above example was just for illustration. The problem that I have is I am in a situation where I don't have the attributes of the model. I know I can get it by _.keys(model.attributes). But I was not willing to over complicate the filter function callback. It would have been great it there was a straight forward way. Appreciate all the help. Thanks

Comment: And I read your first implementation                  `Cars.where({model: 1998}).concat(
    Cars.where({color: "Black"}),
    Cars.where({make: "Honda"})
);`. This suited my situation better. But still looking for a clean solution.

Comment: Could you update the original post with more specifics on what you would like, then? Maybe we can still help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this an old post, but maybe this could be useful to somebody.

I had a similar problem, but a little simplier, this how I solved it

```
var ids=[1,2,3,4];
var plans=this.collection.filter(function(plan){
            var rt=false;
            for(var i=0;i<this.whereOR.length;i++){
                rt=rt||plan.get('id')==this.whereOR[i];
            }
            return rt;
        },{whereOR:ids});
```

I think this could be adapted to solve the problem proposed like this:

```
var search={model: 1998,color: 'Black',make: 'Honda'};
Cars.filter(function(car){
                var rt=false;

                for(key in this.whereOR) {
                    rt=rt||car.get(key)==this.whereOR[key];
                }
                return rt;
            },{whereOR:search});)
```

Hope this help someone!